# How does Spring prevents request body deserialization attacks?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, rce

I have read about deserialization attacks recently and I wonder how does Spring prevent JSON injections. For example let’s consider a request body of a post request, we can instantiate an arbitrary malicious class and execute commands on the server. Are there any mechanisms that check for malicious behavior?

I expect Jackson or other libraries solved these kind of problems.

Comment: I think this https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JAVA-COMFASTERXMLJACKSONCORE-1056418 implies that Jackson >=2.9.10.8 is secure against the attack

Comment: Yes, there are many resources announce  these kind of vulnerabilities but they do not provide solution or bug fixes.